# Why does python have so many ways to interpolate a variable inside a string?

Tags: python

According to this webarticle: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation

One can interpolate a variable by using the `f` function in combination with the mustache signs `{}`. Second one can use the `%-formatter`, third one can use the .format() function on an existing string in combination with again the mustache curls `{}` and lastly there also exists a `Template` class that allows you insert variables in a string like so:

```
name = 'world'
program ='python'
new = Template('Hello $name! This is $program.')
print(new.substitute(name= name,program=program))
```

Why so many different methods to do basically the same thing? Is it because most of those methods came with older python versions and are now considered obsolete?

Thank you

Comment: They each have slightly different use-cases, and were introduced at different times within python's lifetime. They exist to make your life easier. I'd rather use f-strings than `str.format`, but that's not always possible since `str.format` can do padding and all sorts.

Comment: what about the other ones like Template?

Comment: and shouldent you use `ljust()` for padding strings?